# Prerequisite for debugging stored procedure in sql server 2008 and how?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am to debug the stored procedure in sql server 2008, so what should be installed in my system.

Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend

Answer (score 0):

You need [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=7593)

Comment: and what is the process to debug a procedure in the sql server,because I am getting no option for debugging in sql server

Comment: browse the DB where the stored proc you want to edit is located.
Under Programmability > Stored Procedures.
Right Click on the stored proc and select Modify.
You can test your sql statements there.

Comment: I want to check the values of the variables at runtime like we debug .net code using F10 keystroke